# Help me identify these creatures found in sink

Tags: species-identification

The conical flask was kept in a sink for about 3 or 4 week, was waterfilled, and I have no idea if they grown after the flask was waterfilled or before the flask was waterfilled. We do not work with animals so these arenot any experimental material, but maybe they are soil borne if the conical flask contained soil sample (I do not have any idea what was kept in that flask before it was left in that sink) 
[image] 
[image] 
[image] 
They were not moving and they were sticked firmly on the glass wall. They had some constriction marks. Length apporox 0.2 to 0.5 cm, Width approx 0.1 to 0.3 cm. colour pale white to brown.

Comment: Maybe eggshell of something???

Answer (score 2):

I think it's clearly a pupae.
They look like fruit fly pupae, which are very common.
The size also match the description (length of the fruit fly pupa is about 2.5 mm). [image]

Answer (score -1):

I think this will be a larva. Check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fQKihz4dg4I). If it was in a sink, is very probably than will be a fly. But the specie only will be identified with a genome assay, or taxonomically once they out the pupa.

Comment: but mine were not moving

Comment: @AlwaysConfused Pupae don't move around in space. They move around inside but you may or may not see that movement. They look to me a lot like fruit fly pupae but I'm having trouble picturing the scale to know if that's likely true; in any case, if you keep watch over them you will likely find out soon.

Comment: Sorry, i mean larva not pupa. In one phase of the larva-fly transition, the larva stays inmobile, just after the fly out the eggshell. I thinked that was clearly at the final minutes of the video.